# Can DocumentDB successfully act as entire mobile app backend with data and logic

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

DocumentDB on Azure can besides the data hold JavaScript app logic in stored procedures, trigger and user defined functions.

If the app logic is computationally fairly simple (or even if it is not) would it then be a usable solution to have the entire backend in the DocumentDB instance and then have the client apps connecting directly via the DocumentDB REST interface? Or am I missing something in terms of security performance here?

Comment: `client apps connecting directly via the DocumentDB REST interface` --> This is certainly not recommended as in order to connect to DocumentDB, you would need to provide account key in the client application which poses a major security risk to your DocumentDB account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, there are scenarios where you don't need a middle tier and directly perform queries from your javascript client to the DocumentDB.

However, you *don't* want to *expose* a *Master key* to the client, instead you wan't to work with *Resource tokens*, thus you need a small middle tier service that issue a timebound token.

Also see [Securing access to DocumentDB data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data).